# Does Mount Rushmore look the same as in our timeline?

Tags: the-man-in-the-high-castle

In the timeline of "The Man in the High Castle" does Mount Rushmore look the same as in our timeline?

Comment: Construction on Mt. Rushmore went from 1927 to 1941. From [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Rushmore) it sounds like all 4 heads were "roughed out" simultaneously, then "finished" individually. Washington was dedicated in 1934, Jefferson in 1936, Lincoln in 1937, and Roosevelt in 1939, before the "official" start of WW II in Sept. 1939. If the breakpoint between our universe and TMITHC 'verse occurred during WW II all 4 heads should have been finished.

Comment: @JoeL. The point of departure for Man in the High Castle is a different outcome of an attempt to assassinate US President Franklin D. Roosevelt in 1933. He survived in our real history. In the alternate timeline he doesn't (and is replaced by a strongly isolationist president).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears that in the man in the high castle timeline the mountain was not finished in the 5th image you should be able to see at least part of the Roosevelt sculpture at the very least the hairline

[image]

[image]